# How can i get a userinput into an array and then use math.random to get a random question with a random value from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the users names into navne array and then paste the genarize a random name and then a random question with the random name. When the question is used, it should be removed from the array. After this the user should generate a new question. Please help

```js
  

function myFunction() {
    
   var navne = []
var returnword;
var inputElement = document.getElementById("userinput")

returnword = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
    navne.push(returnword);
  inputElement.value = "";  


var randomNavn = navne[Math.floor(Math.random() * navne.length)];
var spørgsmål = [`bund din drink ${randomNavn}`, `tag 2 shots ${randomNavn}`,`del 2 tåre ud ${randomNavn}`]
var randomIndex = spørgsmål[Math.floor(Math.random() * spørgsmål.length)];


alert(randomIndex)

}
```

```html
Indsæt navn <input id="userinput" /><button onclick="addWord()">Add word</button>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="words"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">nyt spørgsmål</button>
```

Comment: ups, that line can just be deleted, edited it now

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet. As you can see, `arrword` is not defined within your `addWord` function

Comment: I've deleted the arrword, it didn't have an effect on the function, it's the navne.push that should add the user input

Comment: You only ever calculate `randomNavn`, `spørgsmål`, etc once at the start of your program when `navne` is empty. You should probably do all that in your `myFunction` function

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, but it will only print the name one time, whereafter it only prints the question without name. Thanks for the help!